# Best practices on typecasting references using dynamic cast

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting, operator-overloading

I need to implement a class that inherits from a purely virtual parent and one of the members I need to code is `operator+=`. But I actually need 2 different versions of this operator - one accepts the virtual parent class as its right-hand side argument and the other accepts the concrete child class (see code below). Which way of typecasting the reference with a `dynamic_cast` is preferred and why - taking a pointer, casting a pointer, checking for `NULL` and dereferencing it back (which is a little bit awkward) or casting a reference and handling an exception that may occur? I've researched some of the Q/As here on stackoverflow and it was suggested that handling an exception is more preferred in situations when successful typecast is rather essential than not (which is not my case). But since modern exceptions are lightweight and fast comparing to how the older mechanism for exception handling performed, maybe exceptions is the way to go? If there are options other than the two I suggested, I'd like to know about them.
Thank you very much.

```cpp
class IRow
{
    ...
public:
    virtual IRow& operator+=(const IRow& rhs) = 0;
    ...
}

class StlBasedRow : public IRow
{
    ...
public:
    ...
    StlBasedRow& operator+=(const StlBasedRow& rhs)
    {
        /*
         * Operator is applied to arguments of the same type
         * which allows faster operation due to knowledge about
         * how elements are stored internally in this particular
         * implementation of the base class IRow
         */
    }

    StlBasedRow& operator+=(const IRow& rhs)
    {
        /*
         *  This one?
         */
        try
        {
            StlBasedRow& rhs_concrete = dynamic_cast<StlBasedRow&>(rhs);
            *this += rhs_concrete;
        }
        catch(std::bad_cast e)
        {
            // operator applied to a base class (IRow)
        }

        /*
         *  Or this one?
         */
        StlBasedRow* rhs_concrete = dynamic_cast<StlBasedRow*>(&rhs);
        if(rhs_concrete != NULL)
        {
            *this += *rhs_concrete;
        }
        else
        {
            // operator applied to a base class (IRow)
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Your code design is bad If you have to do dynamic cast in operator overloading. Anyway if you use pointer in dynamic cast exception will not be thrown, so you can do: `StlBasedRow* rhs_concrete = dynamic_cast<StlBasedRow*>(&rhs);`

Comment: "_But since modern exceptions are lightweight and fast comparing to how the older mechanism for exception handling performed, maybe exceptions is the way to go?_": They are very costly in the exceptional case. I don't think anything has really changed about that. But in any case, `dynamic_cast` itself is also quite costly.

Comment: @MarekR but why is it bad and which are the workarounds for this case?

Comment: Read about double dispatch and visitor pattern.

Comment: @user17732522 how did you measure performance of `dynamic_cast`? Are there known 'benchmarks' for them or are you just telling from your own experience?

Comment: @RedRidingHood In this case I guess it will probably not be too bad, but in general `dynamic_cast` is a rather complicated operation since it has to look through type information of the class hierarchy. In some circumstances this can be simplified, but in general see e.g. the implementation in GCC's sources: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/libsupc%2B%2B/dyncast.cc

Comment: On the other hand a virtual function call is just one pointer indirection and one indirect function call.

Comment: Sometimes `dynamic_cast` is necessary but, more often than not, it can be avoided by redesign.   Best practice is therefore (except in rare cases) to redesign to avoid `dynamic_cast` at all.  In this case, double dispatch and visitor pattern, can help.